# JDBC connection.getschema() AbstractMethodError

Tags: java, jdbc, teradata

I am trying get the default database name from the connection for Teradata. I am using Teradata JDBC Driver 15.10.00.33.

The following code gives me this abstract method error. Can anyone suggest me how I can get default database name using jdbc?

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.teradata.jdbc.jdk6.JDK6_SQL_Connection.getSchema()Ljava/lang/String;
> ```

```
public class TestTDConnection {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String tdConnString = "jdbc:teradata://xx/database=xx";

        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(tdConnString,"xx","xx");
            System.out.println(conn.getSchema());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the javadoc for [`getSchema()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getSchema--), you will notice the following:

> **Since:**
>   1.7

That means you need a Java 7 driver, and the classname in the error message is an obvious indication that you're using a Java 6 driver:

```
com.teradata.jdbc.jdk6.JDK6_SQL_Connection
```

Replace the driver .jar file with a Java 7 (JDBC 4.1) compliant driver.

Or don't use Java 7 features.

Comment: This is the latest driver Teradata have. I guess I have to find another way to get the default database name.

Comment: I'd suggest you ask *them*, since [they claim](http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/jdbcug_chapter_1.html) that Teradata JDBC Driver version 15.10 supports for JDK 8.

Comment: I saw that too. I have posted also on Teradata forum. lets see what I can get. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: I believe the call SELECT DATABASE, USER; would give you the name of the current schema regardless of the J-driver version