# getting database name from teradata jdbc connection string

Tags: java, jdbc, teradata

I am trying to get the default database name from `Teradata JDBC Connection`. I was planning to use `getSchema()` method to get the current database name but unfortunately there is an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41308635/jdbc-connection-getschema-abstractmethoderror/41308878#41308878) with this method in `Teradata jdbc driver`. So, can anyone help with a regular expression to parse the database name from a connection string. Here is a generic connection string for `Teradata jdbc`. Now, I need to get the database name from this string to another variable.

```
String connectionString = "jdbc:teradata://MyDatabaseServer/database=MyDatabaseName,tmode=ANSI,charset=UTF8";
```

Comment: Assuming that `getSchema` would return the database name is a potential mistake, the meaning of schema and catalog is highly database dependent, some databases don't even have those concepts.

Comment: well Teradata does not have schema and catalog concept. As far as I understood so far is that Teradata have users and databases and under user and database all the tables, views, procedures are kept. Although Teradata does not have schema or catalog, the `getSchemas` in `DatabaseMetaData` correctly returns the list of all users and databases. So, I think `getSchema` should return the default database. However, unfortunately this `getSchema` does not work at all.

Comment: `SELECT DATABASE;` returns the current default database and `DATABASE newdb;` sets it within a session.

Comment: @dnoeth Thanks a ton for the solution. It solved my issue. I was looking for a jdbc method to solve this problem but the SQL query also works for me.